# ScrollView Error about only having one child, But there really is only one child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Getting this error; but my ScrollView *does* only have one child (a ConstraintView).  I even added another View on top of that just to be sure.

I've searched around and found some older questions mentioning bugs, but they are from 3 years ago; surely they have been solved by now?

Any help is appreciated, thank you for your time!

Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
   tools:context=".FriendsFragment"
   android:fillViewport="true">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/greyed"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- First Friend -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_icon_1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/person_icon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@string/default_user_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_icon_1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_icon_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_icon_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_touch_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@string/default_last_touch"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_name_1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_name_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_name_1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/options_1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/last_touch_1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_touch_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/last_touch_1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/options_icon" />

        <!-- Second Friend -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_icon_2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/person_icon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_icon_1"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@string/default_user_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_icon_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_icon_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_icon_2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_touch_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@string/default_last_touch"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_name_2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_name_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_name_2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/options_2"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/last_touch_2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_touch_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/last_touch_2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/options_icon" />

        <!-- Third Friend -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_icon_3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/person_icon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_icon_2"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@string/default_user_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_icon_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_icon_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_icon_3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_touch_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@string/default_last_touch"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_name_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_name_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_name_3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/options_3"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/last_touch_3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_touch_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/last_touch_3"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/options_icon" />

        <!-- Fourth Friend -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_icon_4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/person_icon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_icon_3"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@string/default_user_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_icon_4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_icon_4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_icon_4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_touch_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@string/default_last_touch"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_name_4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_name_4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_name_4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/options_4"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/last_touch_4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_touch_4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/last_touch_4"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/options_icon" />

        <!-- Fifth Friend -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_icon_5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/person_icon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_icon_4"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@string/default_user_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_icon_5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_icon_5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_icon_5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_touch_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@string/default_last_touch"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/user_name_5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_name_5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_name_5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/options_5"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/last_touch_5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/last_touch_5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/last_touch_5"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/options_icon" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</ScrollView>
```

Note: This is a prototype, so I've hard-coded a lot of views inside the ConstraintView; I know it's messy.

Comment: Just try by removing LinearLayoutCompat or use LinearLayout instead of LinearLayoutCompat

Comment: @ManojMohanty Hmmm, tried it, but still no effect.  I also tried Nested Scroll view, no improvement either.

Comment: Remove android:fillViewport="true" from ScrollView and Replace androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat to RelativeLayout.

Comment: @MaTTerOOF I did try loading an activity with your UI excluding icons and color stuff and it worked for me without changing anything I would suggest rebuilding the project and try it